# error:Field required in .net c# when not indicated in the model

Tags: c#, .net, model-validation

I am new with .net c# and I have an error while I check if the model is valid, looking at ehe errors in the model it says: **"The EndRepeat field is required."**

Here are some of the lines of my model:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Frecuencia requerida")]
    public int FrecuencyType
    {
        get { return this._frecuencyType; }
        set { this._frecuencyType = value; }
    }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EndRepeat
    {
        get { return this._endRepeat; }
        set { this._endRepeat = value; }
    }
```

**any ideas ?**

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` is a struct, and cannot be null.  Try a `DateTime?` (which equates to a `Nullable<DateTime>`) if you want to allow null values.